# Python Selenium: Calling same WebDriver for multiple function calls

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I want to create 2 Tests (basically the same test, but 1 is in Chrome and the other in Edge). Just a simple connecting to a webpage and confirming some text on the page.

## Original Python Project

If everything is in 1 Python file, it's quite simple:

**test_homepage.py**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# ----------- Connection Test (Chrome) ---------------------------------------------------------------
url = "https://localhost/home"
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

# "Your connection is not private"
driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click() # Click the "Advanced" button
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click() # Click the "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" link
time.sleep(1)

# Login Page
driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys("TestUser")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys("Password123")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
time.sleep(1)

# Search for text on the Homepage to confirm reaching the destination
get_source = driver.page_source
search_text = "Welcome to the Homepage!"
driver.close()

try:
    if (search_text in get_source):
        assert True
        print("Chrome Test: Passed")
    else:
        assert False
except:
    print("Chrome Test: Failed")

# ----------- Connection Test (Edge) ---------------------------------------------------------------
driver=webdriver.Edge("C:\Drivers\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click() # Click the "Advanced" button
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click() # Click the "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" link
time.sleep(1)

# Login Page
driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys("TestUser")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys("Password123")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
time.sleep(1)

# Search for text on the Homepage to confirm reaching the destination
get_source = driver.page_source
search_text = "Welcome to the Homepage!"
driver.close()

try:
    if (search_text in get_source):
        assert True
        print("Edge Test: Passed")
    else:
        assert False
except:
    print("Edge Test: Failed")
```

When testing in Python Selenium, in both browsers, you get an error message `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` when initially connecting to `https://localhost/home`, so I have to confirm advancing to the Login Page, logging in and then checking the Text on the homepage. This code will start with Chrome, and then proceed with the same steps in Edge.

Now, this code is quite inefficient: it's basically doubling the same code. I also plan to create more tests that will involve testing more aspects of the website, meaning the Login process will be necessary for every Test I perform.

## Updated Python Project

As a friend recommended, I should create some functions for this `test_` python file to call.

```
libraries/
├── chrome.py
├── edge.py
tests/
├── test_homepage.py
```

A `libraries` folder for Chrome and Edge Functions (they'll generally be very similar ... and even then, I'm thinking they should probably be combined, but I have a feeling trying to call 2 different WebDrivers from the same library python files will become difficult), and then a `tests` folder for each test (I want to be sure every test is performed in both Chrome and Edge). Here are the updates to my Python Project:

**chrome.py**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class WebChrome:
    def __init__(self):
        print("")
    
    def connect(self, username: str, password: str):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("https://localhost/homepage")
        time.sleep(1)
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        not_private = "Your connection is not private"
        if (not_private in get_source):
            # NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click()
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # Scrolls to the bottom of the page
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        login_page = "Login Page"
        if (login_page in get_source):
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys(password)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
            time.sleep(1)

    def find_string(self, search_text: str):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        self.driver.close()

        try:
            if (search_text in get_source):
                assert True
                print("Chrome Test: Passed")
            else:
                assert False
        except:
            print("Chrome Test: Failed")
```

(I'll get to `edge.py` when I get Chrome working. I also wanted to update my Code so it looks to see whether it's on the "Your connection is not private" or "Login Page" before moving on to the next steps, and that code looks to be working correctly.)

**test_homepage.py**

```
from libraries.chrome import WebChrome
from selenium import webdriver

# ----------- Connection Test (Chrome) ---------------------------------------------------------------
WebChrome().connect("TestUser", "Password123")
WebChrome().find_string("Welcome to the Homepage!")
```

Now, the `connect` function looks to be working as I would expect. However, once Selenium reaches the Homepage, the current Chrome Browser closes out, and a new Chrome Browser appears for a millisecond before ending, causing the Test to Fail.

What I assume is going on: when I call `find_string`, I'm starting a new session because I'm called `self.driver`. I really only want the WebDriver to be called in the `connect` function, and then when I call `find_string` to continue the current driver. However, when I tried including `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")` in `__init__`, Selenium would open 2 Chrome Browsers (the first goes unused) and I run into errors (I'm afraid I don't really understand Constructors too well: all I really know is that `__init__` is supposed to run the code as soon as the Class or Program is started?). I also tried moving `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")` to the beginning of the `WebChrome` class, before the 2 Functions, as well as removing the code from `find_string`, but that causes Syntax Errors when the program runs: `AttributeError: 'WebChrome' object has no attribute 'driver'`

Here is my question: **Where should I call `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")` so it will run only once when I run both the `connect` and `find_string` functions? And is there a better way I should be calling the WebDriver?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `self.driver` in `__init__` and for only once.
You can use `__init__` as `connect` function assuming you need to connect only once.
You are creating a new object every time. You must define `WebChrome` just once for a single test.
As of now, there is no need to pass exe path simply use `webdriver.Chrome()` or `webdriver.Edge()`

#### Different code for edge and chrome

**chrome.py**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class WebChrome:
    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://localhost/homepage")
        time.sleep(1)
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        not_private = "Your connection is not private"
        if (not_private in get_source):
            # NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click()
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # Scrolls to the bottom of the page
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click()
            time.sleep(1)
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        login_page = "Login Page"
        if (login_page in get_source):
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys(password)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
            time.sleep(1)

    def find_string(self, search_text: str):
        get_source = self.driver.page_source
        self.driver.close()

        try:
            if (search_text in get_source):
                assert True
                print("Chrome Test: Passed")
            else:
                assert False
        except:
            print("Chrome Test: Failed")
```

**test_homepage.py**

```
from libraries.chrome import WebChrome
from selenium import webdriver

# ----------- Connection Test (Chrome) ---------------------------------------------------------------
test_obj = WebChrome("TestUser", "Password123")
test_obj.find_string("Welcome to the Homepage!")
```

#### One Code for both edge and chrome

*I recommend this*

**chrome_and_edge.py**
*(Change just the `__init__` function in this way)*

```
class WebBrowser:
    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str,driver_name: str):
        if driver_name == "chrome":
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        elif driver_name == "edge":
            self.driver = webdriver.Edge()
        self.driver.get("https://localhost/homepage")
        time.sleep(1)
        else:
           print("Enter either chrome or edge only!")
           #raise some error
```

**test_homepage.py**

```
from libraries.chrome import WebChrome
from selenium import webdriver

# ----------- Connection Test (Chrome) ---------------------------------------------------------------
test_obj = WebChrome("TestUser", "Password123","chrome")
test_obj.find_string("Welcome to the Homepage!")

# ----------- Connection Test (Edge) ---------------------------------------------------------------
test_obj = WebChrome("TestUser", "Password123","edge")
test_obj.find_string("Welcome to the Homepage!")
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you @Bibhav! I had tried calling `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")` from `__init__` and received an `AssertionError` before, so still confused. And yes, having `connect()` be part of `__init__` makes a lot of sense. And yes, to simply have a String to call for the Driver to be used makes a lot of sense, so I just need a single Library file (for now). Again, thank you!

Comment: Next I need to look into creating a Wait script instead of using `time.sleep` to wait for elements to load (an old Python Programmer I knew made one, but I wasn't quite sure how he did it). I was also thinking of adding the Driver EXEs to the Project directory itself so anyone wanting to use this Test Project wouldn't need to download the Drivers and put them in the path specific by the Program.

Comment: `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))` can be used to wait for elements to load in selenium. Check [`this`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) out. Check update in answer for solution for driver exe.